# Не работает код php

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер! Есть код:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'phpsols') or die ('Cannot open database');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM images';

$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

$numRows = $result -> num_rows;

$result -> close();
```

Который исправно работает. Проблема: когда добавляешь следующие строки перед закрытием result, то код отказывается работать...

```
$error = $conn->errorInfo();

if (isset($error[2])) die ($error[2]);

$numRows = $result ->fetchColumn();

$result->closeCursor();
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: поправил отображение кода... используйте иконку фигурных для выделения кода

Comment: а что подразумевается под "отказывается работать"?
что выдает `var_dump($error)`? Может его не `isset` надо проверять?

Comment: все добавленные строчки браузер бракует, ругается

Comment: О_о БРАУЗЕР??? их вообщето пхп должен обрабатывать... и что пишет-то? в этом суть вопроса была)) что в логах ошибок?

Comment: Даже эту элементарную строчку не берет $error = $conn->errorInfo();

Comment: тааак, что выводится на экран? что выводится в логи?

Comment: Пишет Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пишет Call to undefined method
> mysqli::errorInfo()

ну так вот вам и ответ, такого метода НЕ существует, читайте про [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php)

ps;
откуда вы вообще взяли этот метод?

> mysqli::$errno — Возвращает код ошибки
> последнего вызова функции
> mysqli::$error_list — Возвращает
> список ошибок выполнения последней
> запущенной команды 
> mysqli::$error —
> Возвращает строку с описанием
> последней ошибки

Comment: из книжки взял такой метод. Видимо синтаксис php модифицировался...

Comment: врядли такие серьезные изменения были... errorInfo есть [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php), очень может быть, что просто опечатка в книге.

Comment: но лучше читайте что вам ваш скрипт пишет, если с английским тяжко, то пользуйтесь переводчиком. просто в данном случае вы за зря на элементарную проблему потратили 40 минут)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное он выводит:

```
Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo()
```

Наверное нужно почитать [mysqli.error.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php). нет там никакого errorInfo.

Comment: да выводит именно это